# sql , можно ли хранить 2 значение в одной строке?

Tags: php, sql

Учу php, наткнулся на такое. 
Есть таблица posts, в котором присутствует картинка n-ого поста, под строкой image. А можно ли в одном таком кубике image хранить 2 или 3 директории картинки?

Comment: Хранить можно и обычной строкой адреса к картинкам, с разделителем. Тут дело в том зачем это вам и правильно ли так делать

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По первой нормальной форме БД подразумевается, что вы храните в одной колонке всего одно значение - это часто помогает упростить работу с данными на серверной стороне.

Денормализацию, безусловно, никто не отменял, поэтому если вы хотите хранить несколько значений в одном поле, то можете использовать разделители (получится строка вида CSV) или кодировать в JSON. Поиск и работа с такими данными в зависимости от СУБД может быть разная по сложности в реляционных БД (где-то есть нужные функции, где-то нет).

На мой взгляд, лучше создать отдельную таблицу вида post_images для хранения картинок поста и в самом простом виде создать 2 колонки: post_id и image_url. Безусловно, это новое отношение придется поддерживать в запросах с помощью JOIN.